# Difference between "hereby moves" and "following relief" for change of venue motion

Tags: legal-terms, process, definition, family-law, north-carolina

My sister need to file a motion for a change in venue (in North Carolina) to move a court case from a county she previously resided in to the county where she currently resides.  But we're a bit confused by the questions, specifically the difference in what the first and third question are asking.

Here's the three questions...
1. The undersigned hereby moves this Court to:
2. The undersigned hereby states that the grounds for making this motion include:
3. The undersigned hereby requests the following relief:

It seems like question 1 and 3 are asking about the same thing.  Our goal is to have a judge transfer her case from one county to another.  Can anyone provide clarity as to the difference in what the questions are asking?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: They mean: hire a lawyer

Comment: The "moves" in one is about creating the motion, not about the relocation. Move<->Motion.

Comment: @Dale-M...Unfortunately we do not have the money to hire a lawyer, and while I appreciate you taking the time to read my question, your solution provided no information or help.

Comment: @ a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae - thank you for the clarification. Based on what you said, I'm assuming the first question relates essentially to the type of motion you're filing?  We're filing a motion for a change in venue.  Let me preface, I realize you can't give legal advice :) ...,but would what I said be correct from a procedural point of view?  Thank you again for your input!

Comment: (1) and (3) are very similar in meaning. Usually (1) would be answered quite generally, "moves this Court to change the venue of this proceeding pursuant to Rule 98", while (3) would have an exact word for word statement of what you want an order of the court to say, such as "requests the following relief: (1) that this court immediately transfer venue in this case from the Bennet County District Court of North Carolina to the Simpson County District Court of North Carolina, (2) vacate all pending hearings in this Court, and (3) award the movant her $131 of costs of responding to this motion."

Comment: @ohwilleke thank you so much! That definitely helps clarify the difference :)  I'd like to mark your reply as the answer to my question, but not sure how to do that in a comment.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) and (3) are very similar in meaning.

Usually (1) would be answered quite generally, "moves this Court to change the venue of this proceeding pursuant to Rule 98", while (3) would have an exact word for word statement of what you want an order of the court to say, such as "requests the following relief: (1) that this court immediately transfer venue in this case from the Bennet County District Court of North Carolina to the Simpson County District Court of North Carolina, (2) vacate all pending hearings in this Court, and (3) award the movant her $131 of costs of responding to this motion."